# A surface where velocity is not equal to the product of angular velocity and Distance vector R

Tags: rotational-dynamics

I am trying to imagine a setup where pure rolling is taking place, the COM is definitely moving with a linear speed , say $v$, but the relation 
$v= \omega × R$ does not hold good. Is there any setup possible? My physics professor has said that it is indeed possible .

Comment: I should think in what terms? Maybe slight hints can take my thoughts in the right direction.

Comment: First you say " linear speed $v$" and then write an equation where $v$ is a vector. What exactly do you mean here? Is the *magnitude* of $v$ constant, or $v$ is a constant *vector,* i.e. the direction is also constant? (Probably, answering that question will  also give you a hint about the answer!)

Comment: I mean here that magnitude of v is constant @alephzero